# Downgrading Entity Framework for visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, nuget

I accidentally upgraded my entity framework to EF 6.x but I am working in Visual Studio 2010 which does not have Dbcontext generator template support for ef 6.x, I was wondering if and how I could downgrade it to ef 4.x

I have tried searching in Nugget, 
as well as typing `Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.1.10331` Into the package console but I ended up with errors.

error :

```
Install-Package : Updating 'EntityFramework 6.1.1' to 'EntityFramework 4.1.10331.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'EntityFramework.Extended' that is compatible with 'EntityFramework 4.1.10331.0'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework -Version 4.1.10331
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue ended up being that I also had a package called 
EntityFramework.Extended 6.1.1, This package depended on EF6 and prevented it from being uninstalled, in turn preventing EF4 from being re-installed. Also This Package had no compatible version with EF4.

Upon removing EntityFramework.Extended I was able to fix my error.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Nugget I advise you to do this:

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.1
```

then install the older

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.1.10331
```

"Updating" to an older version will create problems.